# How to use a given database to make queries within a method in django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, decorator

Here is the case. A method or function has a couple of database queries. There are two databases, such as `DATABASE_A` and `DATABASE_B`.

```
def method():
    # database queries here
    orders = Order.objects.filter(...)
    products = Product.objects.filter(...)
```

How to achieve the follows easily with `decorator` or `any other ways`? Can anyone give an `example`? `model.objects.using(some database)` is a known way, however there are a lot of queries in the method. I don't want to touch them, so this is not an option.

```
# Here call method() using DATABASE_A
# here call method() using DATABASE_B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django, Databases, and Decorators](https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/django-databases-and-decorators-14fa1f9a5c97) has a solution using 
[django DATABASE_ROUTERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE_ROUTERS).

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example) you can find an example from [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example). The follows is the summary from 'Django, Databases, and Decorators':

**1. Writing a custom decorator**

Here name the `decorator` as `decorators.py`:

```
from functools import wraps

try:
    from threading import local
except ImportError:
    from _threading_local import local

threadlocal = local()


class use_db_for_reads(object):

    def __init__(self, database_name):
        self.database_name = database_name

    def __enter__(self):
        setattr(threadlocal, 'DB_FOR_READ_ONLY', self.database_name)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        setattr(threadlocal, 'DB_FOR_READ_ONLY', None)

    def __call__(self, test_func):
        @wraps(test_func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return test_func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner


def get_thread_local(attr, default=None):
    return getattr(threadlocal, attr, default)


class AnalyticsRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return get_thread_local('DB_FOR_READ_ONLY', 'default')

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True
```

**2. update settings**

Here is an example of `DATABASES` in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    },
    'read-only': {
        ...
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['decorators.AnalyticsRouter']
```

**3. Here is how to use it**

```
from decorators import use_db_for_reads

# Here call method() using DATABASE_A
with use_db_for_reads(DATABASE_A):
    method()

# here call method() using DATABASE_B
with use_db_for_reads(DATABASE_B):
    method()
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in [Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/) docs:

> You can select the database for a QuerySet at any point in the
>   QuerySet “chain.” Just call using() on the QuerySet to get another
>   QuerySet that uses the specified database.

```
>>> # This will run on the 'default' database.
>>> Author.objects.all()

>>> # So will this.
>>> Author.objects.using('default').all()

>>> # This will run on the 'other' database.
>>> Author.objects.using('other').all()
```

Comment: `using(somedb)` is a known way, however there are a lot of queries in the method. I don't want to touch them. So the way you given is not an option.